# Show folder's contents in finder using Swift

Tags: swift, directory, finder, nsworkspace

I want to be able to select a folder and show its contents in the Finder. I have managed to select the folder itself and select a file within the folder. But I don't know how to show the contents of an empty folder.

e.g.

Folder A/Folder B

I want to display the contents of folder Folder B (which could be empty).

I have written the following code:

```
func showFolder(fileName : String)
{
    var dataPath = homeDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
    var urlPath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: dataPath)
    var selectedURLs = [urlPath!]
    NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().activateFileViewerSelectingURLs(selectedURLs)
}
```

This only opens Folder A with Folder B highlighted. This is very close, but not quite right.

I need to be able to open Folder B with nothing highlighted. I'm obviously using the wrong command.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Use the [`selectFile`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1524399-selectfile) method and pass `nil` as first argument and the path to the folder to be shown as second argument.

```
NSWorkspace.shared.selectFile(nil, inFileViewerRootedAtPath: "/Users/")
```

Answer (score 34):

**2021 | SWIFT 5.1:**

```
func showInFinder(url: URL?) {
    guard let url = url else { return }
    
    if url.isDirectory {
        NSWorkspace.shared.selectFile(nil, inFileViewerRootedAtPath: url.path)
    } else {
        NSWorkspace.shared.activateFileViewerSelecting([url])
    }
}

extension URL {

    ///IMPORTANT: this code return false even if file or directory does not exist(!!!)
    var isDirectory: Bool {
        hasDirectoryPath
    }
}
```

showInFinder:

- Folder's url = will show content of the folder.
- File's url = will open in Finder file's parent and select file there.
- Url is nil = Will do nothing without throw any error
- File/path does not exist = Will do nothing without throw any error

Answer (score 10):

**Swift 2.1 code to Launch OS X Finder**

Use the `selectFile` or `activateFileViewerSelectingURLs` to select files.

Select 1 item in finder with path YOUR_PATH_STRING

```
NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().selectFile(YOUR_PATH_STRING, inFileViewerRootedAtPath: "")
```

The second param use empty string, if you specify an empty string "" for this parameter, the file is selected in the main viewer.

---

If you want to select 1 or more files use `activateFileViewerSelectingURLs(_ fileURLs: [NSURL])`

To select one file

```
NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().activateFileViewerSelectingURLs([NSURL].init(arrayLiteral: NSURL.init(fileURLWithPath: YOUR_PATH_STRING)))
```

To select multiple files

```
let urls : [NSURL] = [NSURL.init(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/USER_NAME/Pictures"),
                      NSURL.init(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/USER_NAME/Music")]
```

If you provide item that are not in the same folder more windows selecting the specified files are open.

```
let urls : [NSURL] = [NSURL.init(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/USER_NAME/Pictures"),
                      NSURL.init(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/USER_NAME/Music"),
                      NSURL.init(fileURLWithPath: "/Users")]
```