# How to open a folder via Finder using Swift in Xcode from a Finder Sync Extension

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, findersync

I am trying to open a specific folder when a user clicks on a menu item in the Finder Sync Extension I am writing.  I know there are many similar questions posted because I have looked at them but none of the solutions are working in my application.

Here is the folder I am trying to open:

```
let folder = "/Users/username/some/folder"
```

This post, [Show folder's contents in finder using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738052/show-folders-contents-in-finder-using-swift), suggested doing the following:

```
NSWorkspace.shared().selectFile(nil, inFileViewerRootedAtPath: folder)
```

When I tired this method, the menu item does nothing when it is clicked.

There are many other posts I have looked at and I have also tried the following methods but I haven't had anything work yet.

```
NSWorkspace.shared().activateFileViewerSelecting([URL(fileURLWithPath: safeZone, isDirectory: true)])
```

This results in the containing folder "some" being opened and the folder I actually wanted to open "folder" is just highlighted.

```
NSWorkspace.shared().openFile(safeZone)
```

When I tired this method, the menu item does nothing when it is clicked.

```
NSWorkspace.shared().open(URL(fileURLWithPath: safeZone, isDirectory: true))
```

When I tried this method, I got a message from Finder stating:

```
The application “MyAppFileSyncExtension” does not have permission to open “folder.”
```

Is there some way via Xcode to give the extension more permissions?  I know my parent app can read and write to this folder no problem.

```
NSWorkspace.shared().openFile(folder, withApplication: "Finder")
```

When I tired this method, the menu item does nothing when it is clicked.

I am guessing that none of these methods are working because I am trying to do this from Finder Sync Extension.  Does anyone know how to get around this issue?

**UPDATE**

I tested those methods from the parent application and most of them work.  The question is how to create this type of behavior from a Finder Sync Extension.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you setup the proper entitlements so the extension can access the folders?

Comment: @I'L'I I don't think so.  How do I do that?  I had an existing application which could access the folders and add a Finder Sync Extension with default settings to the existing application.  How do I set up the entitlements so that the extension can have the same access as the parent application?