# Force a *new* Finder window to open programmatically

Tags: swift, objective-c, macos, cocoa, appkit

I'm implementing a "show in Finder" feature, but it's important that a *new* Finder window should always appear - regardless of which windows are already open.

It seems that Finder always prefers to activate an existing window sharing the same directory; in some cases it will even re-navigate an existing window to highlight the requested path.

I've tried `NSWorkspace.shared.selectFile()` and `NSWorkspace.shared.open()`, as well as running `open` via shell script. All have the same effect.

Is there a way to force Finder to open new windows - even with duplicate paths?

Comment: Use AppleScript to tell Finder to make a new Finder window?

Comment: @matt same behavior there. Strangely enough, on my machine it will create an endless number of windows to ~/Documents, but for every other path it will only create one.

Comment: You cannot do that in macOS.

Comment: Does the AppleScript create a window?

Comment: Maybe you will find here something useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652928/launch-finder-window-with-specific-files-selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this (AppleScript):

```
tell application "Finder"
    set f to document file "eStmt_2021-01-14.pdf" of folder "Downloads" of folder "mattmobile" of folder "Users" of startup disk
    set fol to folder "Downloads" of folder "mattmobile" of folder "Users" of startup disk
    activate
    set w to make new Finder window
    set target of w to fol
    select f
end tell
```

Works fine: every time it runs, it creates a *new* window and shows and selects the target file in that window.

Comment: This works well; I had hoped to find a "native" AppKit API, but that doesn't seem to exist so this is the next best thing.

Comment: Using Apple Script for this will bring up a one time security dialog prompt on macOS 10.14 and newer.

Answer (score 1):

Just call this:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] activateFileViewerSelectingURLs:@[url]];
```

In Swift it should be this:

```
NSWorkspace.shared.activateFileViewerSelecting([url])
```